# saving data in my application using realm

Tags: android, realm

I'm new to android and realm, I'm trying to save data using realm and it worked for one model but when I try to make another class that extends RealmObject I get this "I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 32357 SIG: 9 Application terminated. "

```
    package org.insanps.insanuser.steps.steps_12.step4;

    import io.realm.RealmObject;

    public class StepFourQuestions extends RealmObject {

        private String Q1;
        private String Q2;


        public String getQ1() {
            return Q1;
        }

        public void setQ1(final String Q1) {
            this.Q1 = Q1;
        }
        public String getQ2() {
            return Q2;
        }

        public void setQ2(final String Q2) {
            this.Q2 = Q2;
        }

    }
```

[run error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCOhF.png)

[Logcat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xru8O.png)

Comment: Post relevant code and some *real* error log please, no one can help you like this.

Comment: thanks @HedShafran

Comment: Look at what your Logcat prints while the app crashes, filter for Error and post the error here please.

Comment: I'm 150% sure that your Logcat contains everything you need to know about schema migrations

Comment: right! thanks @EpicPandaForce it worked